# Kafka groups cleanup

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using kafka (v. 0.10.1.1) with some dynamic groups (create new group.id for each new consumer). I have to recheck/filter the past event stream for some criteria, what means after some time I have many groups. Is there a auto cleanup of old unused groups?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to cleanup unused consumer groups manually since Kafka does so for you automatically. All the metadata will be deleted once the last consumer in the group exits, and the offsets will also be removed after `offsets.retention.minutes` amount of time passes.